# Infinite loop goes haywire after a while

Tags: java, infinite-loop

Below my java code to do something every 10 secs in an infinite loop - I replaced what I do in my program with a triple loop so that some cpu cycles are taken up in each iteration. After the triple loop I have a System.out.println that shows the iteration number, the length of the cycle in ms (should be 10 secs of course) and the result of the triple loop. This works fine for a good while, and then all of a sudden (in this case at iteration 160 the duration doubles, and then goes to 0??) it goes haywire, as this output shows...

150: time taken = 9998 and dummy = 0.8775897877771157

151: time taken = 9997 and dummy = 0.8775753358042688

152: time taken = 9997 and dummy = 0.07072216723899125

153: time taken = 9999 and dummy = -0.8011526357338304

154: time taken = 9998 and dummy = -0.936451400117644

155: time taken = 9998 and dummy = -0.21078106590019152

156: time taken = 9998 and dummy = 0.7086804082392084

157: time taken = 10013 and dummy = 0.9765843832906294

158: time taken = 9996 and dummy = 0.346621180094276

159: time taken = 10002 and dummy = -0.6020239375552833

160: time taken = 186326 and dummy = -0.997171023392149

161: time taken = 0 and dummy = -0.47552366901205834

162: time taken = 0 and dummy = 0.48331795366796265

163: time taken = 0 and dummy = 0.9977992786806003

164: time taken = 0 and dummy = 0.594908548461427

165: time taken = 0 and dummy = -0.3549383576518463

166: time taken = 0 and dummy = -0.9784565746221131

167: time taken = 0 and dummy = -0.7023863292684921

168: time taken = 0 and dummy = 0.21945466799406363

169: time taken = 0 and dummy = 0.9395300555699313

170: time taken = 0 and dummy = 0.7958058429196471

171: time taken = 0 and dummy = -0.07957859166428352

172: time taken = 0 and dummy = -0.8817988360675502

173: time taken = 0 and dummy = -0.8732972972139946

174: time taken = 0 and dummy = -0.06189025071872073

175: time taken = 0 and dummy = 0.8064184068658303

176: time taken = 0 and dummy = 0.9333097001669604

177: time taken = 0 and dummy = 0.2021203593127912

178: time taken = 3673 and dummy = -0.7148975077677643

179: time taken = 9998 and dummy = -0.97464190312541

What am I doing wrong??

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Weg {
    long t0;
    long t1;
    long cntr;

    public Weg() {
        t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        cntr = 0;
        //This code arranges the infinite loop...
        ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
        Runnable updateRunnable = () -> {
            try {
                //Do stuff here...
                double dummy = 0;
                int n=10;
                for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
                    for (int j=0; j<n; j++) {
                        for (int k=0; k<n; k++) {
                            dummy = Math.sin(i+j+k+cntr);
                        }
                    }
                }

                t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
                System.out.println(cntr + ": time taken = " + (t1 - t0) + " and dummy = " + dummy);
                t0 = t1;
                cntr++;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        };
        executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(updateRunnable, 10, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Weg();
    }
}
```

Comment: "the duration doubles" - no, it took *186 seconds*... and then ran another 17 times in quick succession, effectively to catch up. My guess is that *something* stopped the code running for 3 minutes, e.g. the computer going to sleep, or you hitting a break point, or you halting console access etc.

Comment: I agree with @JonSkeet, the scheduled executor service computes the time to re-execute after each execution by adding the fixed delay to the currently stored time. Hence, if at iteration 160 you (or the JVM) stopped your code somewhere,  the next N iterations will produce a schedule time which is inferior to the current system's time, causing the scheduled executor to execute your thread right after and that's until when the next execution time will be again larger than the current system time.

Comment: Thanks guys. Could it be different? It executes every 10 secs, but because my screen went to sleep at iteration 160 for 3 minutes, the outputs get queued. Then when I wake the screen up again it *looks* like an iteration lasted 3 minutes and subsequent ones no time at all to catch up, or was the iteration 160 really  3 minutes? If so, I dont ubderstand why subsequent iteration try to catch up? Why dont subsequent iterations simply last 10 secs?

Comment: (sorry clicked return): is there an alternative way you guys know of to get an infinite loop executing every 10 secs that does not have this issue?